# Uniquely identify class instances only knowing about their type and constructor parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, unique, multiple-instances

I searched for days but didn't find anything solving my problem.

### Goal

- I need to uniquely identify class instances by only knowing about their class type,
   their constructor and the function that wants to create them.
- I have an possibly infinite number of Classes: A_Class, B_Class, C_Class, .... 
  All classes extend the Base Class: Base_Class.
- I have one function bar that needs to receive:

  - a Class Type (e.G A_Class),
  - parameters for the constructor of A_Class
- Bar can be a singleton and may receive more than those two arguments
- I have an possibly infinite number of functions afoo, bfoo, cfoo, ... 
  that will call function bar and give it a class type and variables to pass into the class constructor.
- If afoo calls bar with (A_Class, paramsA) for the first time, bar will create a new 
  instance of A_Class, save a reference somewhere and return it.
- If afoo calls bar with (A_Class, paramsA) again, bar should not create a new instance 
  of A_Class, but return the one it has already created.
- If bfoo calls bar with (A_Class, paramsA), bar will create a new instance of A_Class,
   save it and return it. This instance must be different from the one requested by afoo.
- Another constraint: afoo, bfoo, cfoo, ... can possibly request an infinite number of
   instances from bar for the same class. Meaning: If afoo calls bar multiple times
   with the same (A_class and paramsA) bar should treat those as separate instances and always return the right one.

### Pseudo-Code example

```
class A extends BaseClass<ParamsA>{
   constructor(paramsA: ParamsA){}
} 

function bar(Class: ClassType, params: ParamsForClassType){
   if(instance already exists){
     const instance = getSavedInstance(????);
     return instance
   }
   const instance = new Class(params)
   save(instance);
   return instance;
   
} 

function afoo(){
 // No matter how often afoo runs. 
 // It should always get the same instance of A. 
 // This instance of A belongs to afoo
  const aInstance = bar(A, paramsA);
}

function bfoo(){
  // No matter how often bfoo runs. 
  // It should always get the same instance of A. 
  // this instance of A belongs to bfoo. 
  // It is different than the instance of A that afoo has
  const aInstance = bar(A, paramsA);
}

function cfoo(){
 // if a function cfoo calls bar with the exact same arguments multiple times 
 // but it is written differently in code,
 // bar should also treat this as two separate instances
 const aInstance1 = bar(A, paramsA);
 const aInstance2 = bar(A, paramsA);

 // the same applies for loops etc
 // bar should treat these as separate instances 
 //and remember those instances when cfoo wants to retrieve them
 for(let i = 0; i<5; i++){
   let aInstances[i] = bar(A, paramsA);
 }
}
```

### An Analogy

Imagine you have an infinite number of architects that all use the same construction company.

If an architect sends a plan for a house to the construction company,
the construction company should build the house and return the address.

Sometimes an architect might forget that he has already sent plans for a certain house and send them again by accident.

The construction company should not build a new house in that case, but just return the address of the corresponding house it has already built

### What I have tried

- Sending a unique hardcoded key to bar for every requested class instance:

```
function afoo(){
  const aInstance1 = bar(A, paramsA, "UNIQUE_KEY_FROM_AFOO_FOR_A1");
  const aInstance2 = bar(A, paramsA, "UNIQUE_KEY_FROM_AFOO_FOR_A2");
}
```

This works, but I dont want to keep track of the instances myself.

---

- Sending a unique uuidv4 as key to bar

```
function afoo(){
  const aInstance = bar(A, paramsA, uuidv4());
}
```

This doesn´t work because on every execution of afoo, a new uuidv4 is created

---

- Sending the caller line as a key to bar

```
function afoo(){
  
  const aInstance = bar(A, paramsA,(new Error).stack.split("\n")[4]);
}
```

Does not work because of webpack. All functions are in the same line. 
It doesn´t even give me different lines if I get the call_line twice in afoo

---

- Counting how many times bar as been called on each execution of afoo, bfoo etc

```
function afoo(){
  let counterA = 0;
  const aInstance1 = bar(A, paramsA, ++counterA);
  const aInstance2 = bar(A, paramsA, ++counterA);
}
```

Works pretty well. But if an instance is not used for a certain run of afoo, then the system is messed up and won´t correctly retrieve the instance. example:

```
function afoo(){
  let counterA = 0;
  const aInstance1 = bar(A, paramsA, ++counterA);

  // sometimes aInstance2 is requested from bar and sometimes not
  if(Math.random() > 0.5){
    const aInstance2 = bar(A, paramsA, ++counterA);
  }

  const aInstance3 = bar(A, paramsA, ++counterA);
}
```

Comment: You need to narrow down your question.

Comment: In what way? I cannot narrow it down because then it does not specify the Specs I have.

Comment: I don't see how your analogy is related to the problem.

Comment: You already know how to solve this problem to "*uniquely identify class instances by only knowing about their class type and their constructor parameters*", if it were not for "*the function that wants to create them*", right?

Comment: You're asking too many questions which goes against SO guidelines. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: I´m not sure if I understood you correct. Yes: I know how to create a unique id for every class instance. Just set a this.id = uuidv4() in the constructor of BaseClass. 
But that information somehow must reach the function that wanted to create them.

Comment: Have a look on BottleJS or a similar DI library. It might help you. It seems that your `afoo`, `bfoo`, `cfoo` functions could be written as services.

Comment: @sakramento No, that's not what I meant - and `uuidv4()` doesn't actually work as you explained. It seems like what you are looking for is akin to [hash consing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_consing). However, "*If bfoo calls bar, [the returned instance] must be different from the one requested by afoo*" is a weird requirement. Don't do that, it breaks encapsulation. Instead, create one store for each function (or group of functions that should share instances), and explicitly pass that store (or an identifier for it) together with the arguments to your factory function.

Comment: @antoniom that goes in the right direction! I had a quick look and I think I still would need to uniquely identify the instances when i register them

Answer (score 1):

Really the only two viable solutions here are both you have listed: generating unique IDs (by hand) or using counters.

You cannot use the position of the function in your code unless you agree to sacrifice loops, because if you call it in a loop, the position will always be the same so the instance will be the same. So this is not an option.

Now if you don't want to keep track of the instances yourself counters are pretty much the only way to go, and, frankly, a pretty good one. If you are familiar with React, you probably know that this is actually how hooks work. And this is the very reason you are not allowed to call them inside `if` statements or loops. This may be a bit annoying, but you can totally deal with it, if you create all of the instances in the beginning of the function then just use them conditionally. You could also create some factory function that will keep track of this counter by itself to make it prettier (I'll write plain JS for simplicity, but you can absolutely type this)

```
const createFooFunction = (fn) => {
  const cache = new Map()
  return (...args) => {
    let counter = 0
    const bar = (Class, params) => {
      let classCache = cache.get(Class)
      if(!classCache) {
        classCache = []
        cache.set(Class, classCache)
      }
      if(classCache[counter]) {
        return classCache[counter++]
      }
      const instance = new Class(params)
      classCache[counter] = instance
      return instance
    }
    return fn(bar, ...args)
  }
}

const afoo = createFooFunction(bar => {
  const instance1 = bar(A, paramsA)
  const instance2 = bar(A, paramsA)
  const instance3 = bar(A, paramsA)

  if(Math.random() > 0.5) {
    // Do something with instance2
  }
})
```

You could also move the initialization of instances in a separate function so that you don't have a temptation to create instaces inside loops or conditions

```
const createFooFunction = (init, fn) => {
  const instances = init()
  return (...args) => fn(instances, ...args)
}

const afoo = createFooFunction(
  bar => {
    const instance1 = new A(paramsA)
    const instance2 = new A(paramsA)
    const instance3 = new A(paramsA)
    const instances = []
    for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) instances.push(new A(paramsA))
    
    return [instance1, instance2, instance3, ...instances]
  },
  ([instance1, instance2, instance3, ...instances]) => {
    if(Math.random() > 0.5) {
      // Do something with instance2
    }
  }
})
```

An advantage of this approach with `init` function is that

1. You don't even need `bar` or any counters non-sense in the first place
2. You will not have any problems when for example the parameters to `A` is an object like `{foo: 'bar'}` which is a new object with every `afoo` call so the cache doesn't work without you performing some extra object equality checks.

But that's pretty much it, with this approach you cannot create instances inside conditions or loops.

---

Another thing I can think of is combining this with the unique ID approach. You could make `bar` optionally accept a unique ID, if it gets one, it will use it, otherwise it will use a counter. Something in this fashion:

```
const createFooFunction = (fn) => {
  const cache = new Map()
  return (...args) => {
    let counter = 0
    const bar = (Class, params, id) => {
      let classCache = cache.get(Class)
      if(!classCache) {
        classCache = new Map()
        cache.set(Class, classCache)
      }

      const key = id ?? counter++
      if(classCache.has(key)) {
        return classCache.get(key)
      } 

      const instance = new Class(params)
      classCache.set(key, instance)
      return instance
    }
    return fn(bar, ...args)
  }
}

const afoo = createFooFunction((bar, count) => {
  const instance1 = bar(A, paramsA)

  if(Math.random() > 0.5) {
    const instance2 = bar(A, paramsA, 'random_instance')
  }

  const instance3 = bar(A, paramsA)

  for(let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    const instance = bar(A, paramsA, `loop_instance_${i}`)
  }
})
```

Now you can use loops and conditions, but it's now your duty not to forget to assign IDs to `bar` calls that are inside `if` statements in loop. This is a bit of a pain in the neck and it may cause very hard to find bugs, but that's pretty much it, I don't think there is any other way you could solve such problem.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and answering. Yeah React does it like that. And that is precicely what I want to do. I´m building a react kind of library. I also saw react uses stringified props and class name as keys. I took those as well and hashed it.  It´s still not ideal though. Maybe I´ll bring in the counter as well
If you want to check it out: https://github.com/MarvinScheffold/string-work